# Main Search Form in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm really new in Yii2 and I still don't know how to configure it properly. I noticed that the `GridView` has search fields on each column. What I need now is to create a main/single search field wherein a user can input keywords then results will show in the `GridView` after hitting the search button.

Is this possible? I also used this Kartik widget in my search form field which has a dropdown list in it. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtO1K.png).

We're told to use this dropdown search and when the user inputs some keywords (sometimes returns 'No results found' on the dropdown list), and clicks the Search button, the page will refresh displaying all the results based on the keywords inputted.

I also searched some problems same as mine here in SO, such as these:

> [Yii2 Search model without using GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000276/yii2-search-model-without-using-gridview)
>
> [yii 2 , make an active form text field master search field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745249/yii-2-make-an-active-form-text-field-master-search-field)

I found no luck. The second link doesn't have any answers.

I will include my action controller here in case you need it.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $searchModel = new PayslipTemplateSearch();

    $PayslipEmailConfig = PayslipEmailConfig::find()->where(['company_id'=> new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->one();

    $payslipTemplateA = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'A'])->one();
    $payslipTemplateB = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'B'])->one();

    $pTemplateModel = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->all();
    $user = User::find()->where(['_id' => new \MongoId($session['user_id'])])->one();
    $module_access = explode(',', $user->module_access);


    $dataProvider = User::find()->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'PayslipEmailConfig' => $PayslipEmailConfig,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'payslipTemplateA' => $payslipTemplateA,
        'payslipTemplateB' => $payslipTemplateB,
    ]);
}
```

My view, *index.php*

```
<?php 
    $users = User::find()->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();
    echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => new User(), 'users' => $users]); 
?>
```

*_search.php*

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['searchresults'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'id' => 'searchForm'
]); ?>

<?php   
    $listData = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $listData[(string)$user->_id] = $user->employeeId. ' '.$user->fname.' '.$user->lname;
    }
    
    echo $form->field($model, '_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $listData,
        'addon' => [
                'append' => [
                    'content' => Html::button('Search', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']),
                    'asButton' => true
                ]
        ],
        'options' => [ 'class' => 'dropdown-responsive', 'responsive' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Search employee ID or name (e.g. 10015 or John Cruz)', 'id' => 'user_id', 'name' => 'id'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'responsive' => true
        ],
    ]);
?>            

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Really need help for this one.

Comment: can you post your `index.php` file?

Comment: You need to pass `searchModel` to index file. and than that `searchModel` pass to `_search` file as `model`.

Comment: so I will use this instead, `echo $this->render('_search', ['searchModel' => new User(), 'users' => $users]); ` ?

Comment: No. like as this  `$searchModel = new UserSearch();    echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel, 'users' => $users]);`

Comment: ok. but how does it work?

Comment: Can you post `_search` file code . i give example for this.

Comment: ok. done posting it.

Comment: you need to filter base on `User` or `UserSearch` model ?

Comment: based on `User`. but which is better and correct?

Comment: UserSearch is best for searching.

Comment: yes. but I have my data in `User`. is it possible to also put my data (database fields) in `User` to `UserSearch`?

Comment: you need to add where condition in `UserSearch`'s search function. like as after `$query->User::find();` line  add following line `$query->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])]);`

Comment: done. after which? can you place put an answer? so I could follow it. thanks

Comment: I put ans. so check it out..

Answer (score 1):

This example code as per your requirement. so, try it.

User Searchmodel's `search()` method.

```
public function search($params)
{
   $query = User::find();
   $query->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();

   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
  ......
  ........
}
```

Controller's `actionIndex`

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    /*  $searchModel = new PayslipTemplateSearch();  */

    $PayslipEmailConfig = PayslipEmailConfig::find()->where(['company_id'=> new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->one();

    $payslipTemplateA = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'A'])->one();
    $payslipTemplateB = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'B'])->one();

    $pTemplateModel = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->all();
    $user = User::find()->where(['_id' => new \MongoId($session['user_id'])])->one();
    $module_access = explode(',', $user->module_access);

    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    /*
       $dataProvider = User::find()->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();
    */

    return $this->render('index', [
        'PayslipEmailConfig' => $PayslipEmailConfig,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'payslipTemplateA' => $payslipTemplateA,
        'payslipTemplateB' => $payslipTemplateB,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
```

and `index.php`

```
<?php 
    $users = User::find()->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();
    echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel, 'users' => $users]); 
?>
```

Comment: but I am using Kartik as my search field. it has a dropdown list for searching. does this matter?

Comment: it's not working since it's Kartik. it has a dropdown and it only displays results based on the dropdown list. here's an image: http://i.imgur.com/dNhzdeQ.png please help.

Comment: I asked another question related to this one, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900328/how-to-implement-single-search-form-in-yii2

Comment: I hope you can still help. :(

Comment: yes.. i creating working demo locally, so please  have some patience... :)

Comment: glad to hear that. thank you. I hope you could refer to my new question. thank you :)