# How to implement single search form in yii2

Tags: php, search, gridview, yii2

Yii2 has a `searchModel` to search each field in the `GridView`. Is it possible to just create a single search field outside the `GridView` where the user can input keywords and by the time Search button is hit, the results will display in the `GridView` based on the keywords entered.

CONTROLLER

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    //$searchModel = new PayslipTemplateSearch();

    $PayslipEmailConfig = PayslipEmailConfig::find()->where(['company_id'=> new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->one();

    $payslipTemplateA = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'A'])->one();
    $payslipTemplateB = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'B'])->one();

    $pTemplateModel = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->all();
    $user = User::find()->where(['_id' => new \MongoId($session['user_id'])])->one();
    $module_access = explode(',', $user->module_access);

    //$dataProvider = User::find()->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])])->all();
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'PayslipEmailConfig' => $PayslipEmailConfig,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'payslipTemplateA' => $payslipTemplateA,
        'payslipTemplateB' => $payslipTemplateB,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
public function actionSearchresults($keyword)
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if ( $keyword == '') {
        return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());
    } else {
        $user = User::find()->where( [ '_id' => new \MongoId($id) ] )->one(); 
        $searchModel = new PayslipTemplateSearch();

        $payslipTemplateA = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'A'])->one();
        $payslipTemplateB = PayslipTemplate::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])->andwhere(['template_name' => 'B'])->one();

        return $this->render('searchresults', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'user' => $user,
            'payslipTemplateA' => $payslipTemplateA,
            'payslipTemplateB' => $payslipTemplateB,
        ]);
    }    
}
```

I asked a question connected to this problem here: [Main Search Form in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882097/main-search-form-in-yii2)

It didn't due to some complications in Kartik's `Select2` search dropdown widget. Now I switched temporarily to a simple Yii2 search field.

VIEW

```
echo $form->field($model, '_id')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'search'))->label(false);
```

MODEL

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\User;

/**
 * UserSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\User`.
 */
class UserSearch extends User
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[/*'_id',*/ 'creator_id'], 'integer'],
            [['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'username', 'user_type'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $session = Yii::$app->session;

        $query = User::find();
        $query->where(['user_type' => 'BizStaff'])->andwhere(['parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner'])]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            '_id' => $this->_id,
            'creator_id' => $this->creator_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fname', $this->fname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'lname', $this->lname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_type', $this->user_type]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to I implement a single search? It's kind of a smarter search since it can search everything in the database table based on keywords inputted.

EDIT

When I search a keyword, say for example 'hello', it then gives me this url and error after hitting enter key:

URL:

> http://localhost/iaoy-dev/web/index.php?r=payslip-template%2Fsearchresults&PayslipTemplateSearch%5B_id%5D=hello

Error message:

> Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Help.

Comment: you have pass `id` as parameter in `payslip-template/searchresults` action ?

Comment: have you use `searchresults` as action of `ActiveForm` in _search.php ?. and above all code are working, if you used `searchresults` as action of form in _search.php so it replace with `index` action..

Comment: something's weird in my URL: `/index.php?r=payslip-template/searchresults&PayslipTemplateSearch[_id]=samplekeyword`

Comment: You use `index` action instead of `searchresults`. by this its work. because of you used the `id ` parameter in `searchresults` action like as `searchresults($id)`.

Comment: okay I get it. but why is there a `PayslipTemplateSearch[_id]=sampleke‌​yword` in my URL?

Comment: can you put an answer where you can show a simple `searchresults` page? because my original `searchresults` page is not working.

Comment: `PayslipTemplateSearch[_id]=sampleke‌​yword` is search param for `_id`.

Comment: can you put `searchresults` code ?. and `searchresults` is search model ?

Comment: done. but don't bother with it because it is not working

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and my solution is:

**Model**

Extend your UserSearch Model with a search parameter

```
class UserSearch extends User
{
    public $searchstring;
    ...
```

Enable passing the variable

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['searchstring'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
```

Change your search-Method (beware: the searchfields are combined with `orFilterWhere`, depends on your needs).

```
     $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'fname', $this->searchstring])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'lname', $this->searchstring])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->searchstring])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->searchstring])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'user_type', $this->searchstring]);
```

**View** (could be also layout)

Extend your form with a search-input. You can style the input-field by yourself, this is just an example:

```
<?php
/* @var $searchModel app\models\UserSearch */
echo $form->field($searchModel, 'searchstring', [
        'template' => '<div class="input-group">{input}<span class="input-group-btn">' .
        Html::submitButton('GO', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) .
        '</span></div>',
    ])->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Search']);
?>
```

**Controller**

Also check for the value of `$searchstring` after posting the form.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    ...
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    ...
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

That's it.